# read.csv.ffdf gets stuck in R using the ff and ffbase package

Tags: r

I ran read.csv.ffdf from the ff or ffbase package. But it got stuck with the following message

```
read.table.ffdf 1..1000 (1000)  csv-read=0.15sec ffdf-write=1.24sec
read.table.ffdf 1001..63015 (62015)  csv-read=9.89sec ffdf-write=8.84sec
read.table.ffdf 63016..125030 (62015)  csv-read=8.18sec ffdf-write=6.74sec
read.table.ffdf 125031..187045 (62015)  csv-read=8.15sec ffdf-write=6.72sec
read.table.ffdf 187046..249060 (62015)  csv-read=8.19sec ffdf-write=6.72sec
read.table.ffdf 249061..311075 (62015)  csv-read=8.05sec ffdf-write=7.13sec
read.table.ffdf 311076..373090 (62015)  csv-read=8.26sec ffdf-write=6.73sec
read.table.ffdf 373091..435105 (62015)  csv-read=8.26sec ffdf-write=6.8sec
```

The files contains approximately 800000 rows but why does it stop here and I can't run anything from this point onwards?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the transFUN argument of read.csv.ffdf? If yes, make sure the number of rows which you return from transFUN is the same as the number of rows of the data.frame entering transFUN.

Explanation:
Importing of read.csv.ffdf stops when a chunk returns less records then the next.rows argument, so if you are subsetting in transFUN, it will stop. transFUN is for adding derived fields or cleaning up data, not subsetting.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using transFUN at all. I am using just the parameter that specifies the column types. Can read.csv.ffdf handle nulls?

Comment: Could your dataset be malformed?  Does it have a non-constant number of separator values?

Comment: If you don't use transFUN, your dataset must be malformed. Have a look in your dataset starting from row 435106 to the next 62015 rows to see where your csv file does not look as expected.

Comment: Yes, but probably not all rows which are in your file. Can you check that.

Comment: I checked the data seems fine. I suspect it's due to my harddrive (a SSD) having limited space. I understand that while reading the csv it writes to a location somewhere. Where do I set where it outputs the physical data to? I tried setwd. But it still failed at the same point.

Comment: What does length(readLines(con = "pathtoyourfile")) give you and nrow(read.csv("pathtoyourfile"))?

Comment: The first gave me 800001 and the second 800000!

Comment: Then without showing the data and the code, it is impossible to help. If you can read the file in using read.csv, you can check whether it is a data issue by using write.csv of your imported data and using read.csv.ffdf on your writed dataset. The conclusion from that will probably be that your file is malformed. Have you checked that?